# Dynamic Query with MATCHES in Progress 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have to create a query in which people can input some values or not. If they don't input them, the program will search for everything. And people can put just a part of the data of the code. My code became something like this.

```
cQuery = "" +
" FOR EACH table1 " +
" WHERE table1.status_ = 1 " +
" AND table1.section MATCHES " + QUOTER("*"+ pc-section + "*").
```

So my question.
1 - I read a lot that MATCHES uses a table scan and we should avoid it so I thought about putting MATCHES in an if variable. Is it really necessary?
2 - is the QUOTER("*"+ pc-section + "*") the correct way of using MATCHES in a dynamic query? My results seem wrong and I don't know if it was because of the MATCHES or if there is another problem in my code.

Sorry for any wrong ideas and thanks for your time.

EDIT:
My IF statement is like this:

```
DEF VAR ifSection AS CHAR.
    IF pc-section <> "" THEN ifSection = " AND table1.section MATCHES " + QUOTER("*"+ pc-section + "*").
```

And in my code i use:

```
    " FOR EACH table1 " +
    " WHERE table1.status_ = 1 " + ifSection.
```

I managed to make it work now. The problem in my results was because I forgot to add 'ifSection' after THEN. But I still am not sure if this is the best way to do it. Is there another better way to use MATCHES in a dynamic query? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `IF` statements in a `WHERE` clause - you will never, ever use an index that way.

You can put the `IF` around the outside:

```
cQuery = " FOR EACH table1 WHERE table1.status_ = 1 ".
IF <something> THEN
   // no index
   cQuery = cQuery + " AND field-name MATCHES " + QUOTER("*"+ pc-section + "*").
ELSE
IF <something-else> THEN
   // may be indexed
   cQuery = cQuery + " AND field-name BEGINS " + QUOTER(pc-section).
ELSE
IF <something-else> THEN
   // may be indexed
   cQuery = cQuery + " AND field-name = " + input-value.
```

etc, which will help you at least try to use indexes where possible.

Replacing `MATCHES` with indexed searching is more complex. You could look at word indexes and the [`CONTAINS`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-programming-interfaces-122/page/Examples-of-the-CONTAINS-operator.html) keyword as a start.